# Transmitting and storing passwords securely

Tags: java, security

I am only a beginner developer and am doing this more to practise my skills.

I am developing a client server application in which the server will host a game and the clients will log in using a username and password.
Firstly:
Once the user enters their id and password, what would be the simplest way to have this sent to the client securely?  Do I have to right my own encryption method or are there predetermined protocols that can easily be accessed using the java built in libraries?  I have heard of TLS and SSL but am unsure how to make use of these.

Secondly, for security purposes I of course do not want the passwords stored on the server to be saved as plain text.  Instead it would be great if instead of storing the password, a hash digest of the password is stored.  In a text file for easy comparison.  Is there a simple way of producing a hash digest?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption:
  If you are going to use HTTP protocol for communication, you should use HTTP over SSL.
  It provides encryption/decryption to the data transferred between client and server. It 
  will also help you avoid attacks such as tampering, eavesdropping, man-in-the-middle
  attack.

If you have your own protocol for communication, you can always use existing algorithms
  like RSA to generate a key pair. When user logs in, let the application encrypt the 
  password with the public portion of the Server's key, and server will decrypt it using 
  its own private key.

Hashing:
  For hashing you can use SHA-2. (MD5 and SHA-1 can also be used, but SHA-2 is safer.)
  You can store the hash of the password in the database and match it against when the user 
  logs in.